Derivation of Dual problem from Primal problem with Lagrange
I'm currently preparing for test in non-linear optimization, and are trying to learn how to derive the dual problem from primal problem using Lagrange relaxation. The answer I get ends up being the wrong one, and I would really like to get someone who knows this take a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
My solution in short steps;

Rewrite the primal problem so that the constraints are on canonical form
Lagrange relax the problem and rewrite it
Use Complementary Slackness theorem to determine bounds and avoid divergence to +inf.
Formulate the dual problem

Maximize:
$$ z = 6x_1 - 3x_2 - 2x_3 + 5x_4 $$
Subject to:
$$ 4x_1 + 3x_2 - 8x_3 + 7x_4 = 11 $$
$$ 3x_1 + 2x_2 + 7x_3 + 6x_4 \geq 23 $$
$$ 7x_1 + 4x_2 + 3x_3 + 2x_4 \leq 12 $$
$$ x_1, x_2 \geq 0$$
$$ x_3 \leq 0$$
$$ x_4 \text{ is free} $$

Rewriting constraints on canonical form gives me

$$ 4x_1 + 3x_2 - 8x_3 + 7x_4 - 11 = 0 $$
$$ -3x_1 - 2x_2 - 7x_3 - 6x_4 + 23 \leq 0 $$
$$ 7x_1 + 4x_2 + 3x_3 + 2x_4 - 12 \leq 0 $$

Lagrange relations gives me

$$L(\bar{x}, y_1, y_2, y_3) = 6x_1 - 3x_2 - 2x_3 + 5x_4\\
+y_1 \left( -11 + 4x_1 + 3x_2 - 8x_3 + 7x_4 \right)\\
+y_2 \left( 23 - 3x_1 - 2x_2 - 7x_3 - 6x_4 \right)\\
+y_3 \left( -12 + 7x_1 + 4x_2 + 3x_3 + 2x_4 \right)$$

Gathering terms using Complementary Slackness theorem:

$$L(\bar{x}, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4) =
+ x_1 \left( 6 + 4y_1 - 3y_2 + 7y_3 \right)\\
+ x_2 \left( -3 + 3y_1 - 2y_2 + 4y_3 \right)\\
+ x_3 \left( -2 - 8y_1 - 7y_2 + 3y_3 \right)\\
+ x_4 \left( 5 + 7y_1 - 6y_2 + 2y_3 \right)
$$
$$x_1 \geq 0 \implies 6 + 4y_1 - 3y_2 + 7y_3 \leq 0$$
$$x_2 \geq 0 \implies -3 + 3y_1 - 2y_2 + 4y_3 \leq 0 $$
$$x_3 \leq 0 \implies -2 - 8y_1 - 7y_2 + 3y_3 \geq 0 $$
$$x_4 \in R^n \implies 5 + 7y_1 - 6y_2 + 2y_3 = 0 $$
Which gives me the dual
Min $$w = 11y_1+23y_2+12y_3$$
Subject to
$$ -4y_1 + 3y_2 - 7y_3 \geq 6 $$
$$ -3y_1 + 2y_2 - 4y_3 \geq -3 $$
$$ 8y_1 + 7y_2 - 3y_3 \leq -2 $$
$$ -7y_1 + 6y_2 - 2y_3 = 5 $$
The correct dual constraints are
$$ 4y_1 + 3y_2 + 7y_3 \geq 6 $$
$$ 3y_1 + 2y_2 + 4y_3 \geq -3 $$
$$ -8y_1 + 7y_2 + 3y_3 \leq -2 $$
$$ 7y_1 + 6y_2 + 2y_3 = 5 $$
